# How to add localization for default data annotations validation error messages in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, localization, .net-6.0, data-annotations

The idea is to make use of the default messages for fast development of apps and for cleaner code, but I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

This is how far I got:

```
// Program.cs:
using ...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o => {
        o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName!);
            return factory.Create("SharedResources", assemblyName.Name!);
        };
    });
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "es-CL" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture("es-CL")
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
...
app.Run();
```

And the model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; } = null!;

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? Apellido { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [Phone]
        public string? Telefono { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With the resources files I tried a bunch of different keys but none works:

```
// SharedResources.cs:
public class SharedResources { /* empty class */ }

// SharedResources.en-US.resx:
"Required"                          "The {0} field is required."
"RequiredAttribute"                 "The {0} field is required."
"RequiredAttribute_ValidationError" "The {0} field is required."
"The {0} field is required."        "The {0} field is required."
"The0FieldIsRequired"               "The {0} field is required."
"TheFieldIsRequired"                "The {0} field is required."

// SharedResources.es-CL.resx:
"Required"                          "El campo {0} es requerido."
"RequiredAttribute"                 "El campo {0} es requerido."
"RequiredAttribute_ValidationError" "El campo {0} es requerido."
"The {0} field is required."        "El campo {0} es requerido."
"The0FieldIsRequired"               "El campo {0} es requerido."
"TheFieldIsRequired"                "El campo {0} es requerido."
```

It only works if I declare the attribute like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
```

But I need to declare it like the following for fast development and cleaner code:

```
[Required]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your requirement can't be implemented.

We have [a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable?view=aspnetcore-8.0) here which mentioned `If the localized value of "About Title" isn't found, then the indexer key is returned, that is, the string "About Title".` and I think this means we require a key to search in the resource file to get a replacement as a response.

I test in my side with your code snippet, and I found it I used `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]`, then the output would be the desired localized content.

[image]

Since we couldn't leave the `Name` column to be empty, so I'm afraid we have to define a "key" then use this key in Data annotation to make it work.

[image]

Comment: and I'm afraid if you delete `"The {0} field is required."        "The {0} field is required."`,  you would find that `[Required(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]` wouldn't work as well...

Comment: Yes that's what I am experiencing. Whatever goes in ErrorMessage that matches a resource with the same Name, will translate to the resource Value. But if I omit ErrorMessage "The {0} field is required." will be used but it wont work as a key to select "El campo {0} es requerido.". If ErrorMessage doesn't match a resource key, then ErrorMessage value will be shown. What I did at the end was to create an implementation of IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider and an adapter for each attribute for applying localization in the GetErrorMessage method.

Comment: that sounds to be a good workaround, thanks for your response : )

Comment: You're wellcome. Just want to add that on top I also had to create an extension or reimplementation of each data annotation attribute class to be localized, and use attributes like LocalizedRequiredAttribute. Still not what I was looking for, still think it's not a solution, but I prefer to do `[LocalizedRequired]` instead of something like `[Required(ErrorMessage = "ResourceName")]`.